# Create multiple validation lists with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have 50 dynamic named ranges that are called "Line1_S", "Line2_S", "Line3_S",... to "Line50_S".

On my sheet "Pricing Tool", I want to create 50 validation (drop down) lists in cells C7 to C56.

Cell C7 should have named range "Line1_S", Cell C8 should have "Line2_S" and so forth until C56 has "Line50_S".

I keep getting an error in the formula part of my code; can you please have a look and help me resolve the issue?

```
Sub test()

Dim j As Integer

For j = 1 To 50

    With Sheets("Pricing Tool").Cells(j + 6, 3).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Line" & j & "_S" ' this is where the error occurs
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help!

Edit - below a sample named range:

```
=OFFSET('Size Selection'!$E$4, 0, 0, 1, COUNT(IF('Size Selection'!$E$4:$AJ$4="", "", 1)))
```

Comment: what exactly error says? code works fine for me, check names of all your named ranges for tipo

Comment: Thanks for your help simoco. It says Run-time error '1004'; Application-defined or object defined error. The named ranged seem good

Comment: check the _Scope_ of your named ranges: http://trumpexcel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Named-Range-from-New-Name-Box.png . Are they have workbook or sheet scope?

Comment: All workbook scope simoco

Comment: can you somehow share your workbook (e.g. using https://www.dropbox.com) because I don't see something wrong with your code

Comment: I have added a sample named range - does that help? This is for Line1_S

Comment: it works only if `OFFSET(..)` doesn't return `#REF!`

Comment: Ahh I managed to sort it out! your clue put me on the right track. Essentially, the offset is governed by other drop down lists, and some of these did not have a selection in them, i.e. they were empty. Hence the offset returned #REF!. If you put up an answer I'll accept your solution. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, error triggered by `OFFSET(..)` when it returns `#REF!`.

> the offset is governed by other drop down lists, and some of these did not have a selection in them, i.e. they were empty

The main idea how to solve it is to choose something from drop-down lists that `Offset` returns something (not `#REF!`), run code (it applies validation) and then clear drop-down lists.